# Will the Ubuntu file system get any bigger in the future?

Tags: 22.04

The current installation size of Ubuntu is 10GB.  Will this get bigger in the future?

I'm just curious because I installed Ubutnu on my 64GB laptop and wondering if the system file size get any bigger or they will make sure to keep the file system small?

Comment: It will gradually get larger as you use it and or install more software. Or if you download large files and dont delete them.

Comment: you mean later versions? probably will get a bit larger, but hopefully not much larger :)

Answer (score 2):

You should assume that the storage required of system files will grow.

Whether it grows quickly or slowly depends upon your usage and your admin skill.

64GB is plenty of space for a general-purpose desktop...unless your start keeping lots of virtual machines, downloaded movies, and other big files.

Learn how to use the `df` and `du` commands and your Disk Usage Analyzer application. Use those commands to monitor your available and used storage.  All three are included with every stock install of Ubuntu Desktop. As the human, YOUR job is to understand what those tools are telling you and to make sensible decisions accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Operating System installs, and software generally, have been growing continuously as if getting ahead of [Moore’s Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) is a personal challenge to developers. Seriously though, as hardware gets more complex and varied, so does the software that runs it. User expectations grow perhaps even faster - videoconferencing is standard now and requires many components to work; those software components depend on software components, varied and diverse especially in free or open source software. There are multiple ways of getting something done, and the OS needs to support all of them, new and old.

There are GNU/Linux distros oriented toward minimalism as well as projects like Chrome OS (which reimagines terminals and mainframes as web browsers and The Cloud), but Ubuntu is a works-out-of-the-box distro for everyone, so expect it to grow as the hardware and software universes grow along with increasing user expectations.